# how to resolve issue "addEventListener" "click" not working in javascript,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I am trying to add "addEventListener", I was testing one of the examples but it's not working. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong or missing something?

```
<body>
    <div class="emoji-row ng-scope" ng-repeat="...">
        <div class="emoji-wrapper">
            <div class="emoji-reactions">
                <div class="emoji-reactions-main">
                    :)
                </div>
                <div class="emoji-reactions-panel">
                    <ul>
                        <li> :) </li>
                        <li> :( </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="helloemoji"></span>
    </div>
    <script>
        const tag = document.createElement("span");
        tag.className = 'helloemoji';
        document.getElementsByClassName("emoji-row")[0].appendChild(tag);

        const emojis = document.getElementsByClassName("emoji-reactions-panel")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
        console.log(emojis.length); /* 5 */

        Array.from(emojis).forEach(function (item) {
            console.log("item", item);
            item.addEventListener('click', emojiClickfunc);
        });

        function emojiClickfunc() {
            console.log("clicked...")
            alert('clicked...');
        }
    </script>

    <!-- style -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I created a sample [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ko_1234/ernqchy4/2/), but strange it's working there! but not with my above code :(

Would appreciate some guidance on how I can resolve this.

**EDIT:**

while doing random changes, add click on a window

```
        Array.from(emojis).forEach(function (item) {
            console.log("item", item);
            window.addEventListener('click', emojiClickfunc);
        });
```

I am struggling to try and find a solution to this. I need to find out which line of an unordered list was clicked by item, not through a window.

Comment: what exactly is not working in your code? what error do you get? is not showing the alert? or the console.log() not giving you any response?

Comment: the function is not going to call, I didn't see console.log("clicked..."); alert('clicked...'); with my above code, the console is blank even after clicking... on emoji

Comment: Everything is working properly in the example you linked. Are you trying to run it as a simple HTML page or as part of AngularJS app? Is it a fragment of a larger app?

Comment: hello @all,  I don't know why but when I tried window instead of item then I got "clicked..." (alert + console log message) ```Array.from(emojis).forEach(function (item) {
            console.log("item", item);
            window.addEventListener('click', emojiClickfunc);
        });```, can anybody explain why is that so?

Comment: what changes do I have to do? for add click on "item"?

Comment: Bind the `emojuClickFn` to the `ng-click` handler of each `li`. The event from `addEventListener` runs outside the angular zone and is not seen by the application. Welcome the highly opinionated world of AngularJs.

Comment: @Marty https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_12 Please stop using "I have no experience" as an excuse. Take some tutorials instead of doing what seems completely backwards in an Angular world. I don't see a single line of AngularJS code here...

Comment: I'm not going to do your work for you. I told you what the problem is. Someone else kindly provided a link showing you how to do it. Get rid of the `script` tag, move the emoji function into your controller and bind the element to it with `ng-click`. Easy peasy.

Comment: @TheHeadRush I'm not sure about not being in an ngZone is the problem; the handler does not need to trigger detection since it's just calling `console.log`

Comment: No, I didn't mean to give an excuse, actually was in rush hours after trying to do some approach, so instead of getting more confused I asked directly here

Comment: @Marty We are telling you that you are going down a rabbit hole. Re-implement your code using the AngularJS way, then you can ask a question if it's not working. We do not write that kind of code in Angular applications unless we know a lot about how it works and why it must be done that way. Building a DOM and setting/unsettting handlers for you is the core of Angular.

Comment: okay, let me check and follow the steps! will update if any, please help to resolve further doubts if I will face any! :)

Comment: @TheHeadRush [This  example](https://codepen.io/jmendes/pen/LYmxePz) seems to work fine setting a handler from standard JS and calling `console.log()`. Click on the header.

Comment: @Marty - do some kind of angularJS tutorial. This is NOT the way to do angular and you'll only experience pain and frustration until you learn the basics. This website is not here to teach you the basics. Take some free online tutorial.

Comment: Hello again @all! I took all advice positively and have gone through the AngularJS tutorial. I have learned the basics, thanks for the guidance otherwise I think I had gotten stuck to this and hadn't figured it out. I just have resolved the issue, it's in a working state now. Cheers to the advisers! Have a great day ahead! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with AngularJS, but if you are using it and the issue seems to be specific to it, maybe you could try doing things AngularJS way?

Like with ng-click directive
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: Hello, I'm using the ng-click directive. try to archive by js

Comment: @Marty Why? You should not set handlers and create DOM nodes manually, especially if you don't know AngularJS. It sounds really weird that you are using a technology you don't know but you are trying to do something that goes against the way it works. If you must do it that way, you should explain why you're going against the grain.